# Can "MaxConcurrentStreams" server option be considered an equivalent to "maximum_concurrent_rpcs" from grpc-python?

Tags: grpc-go

I am implementing a grpc server(in go) where I need to respond with some sort of server busy/unavailable message in case my server is already servicing a set maximum number of RPCs (currently).

I have implemented a grpc server with grpc-python earlier where I achieved this with a combination of `maximum_concurrent_rpcs` and the max number of threads in the `threadpool`. I am looking for something similar in grpc-go. The closest I could find was the server setting which can be set by the ServerOptions returned by calling `MaxConcurrentStreams`. My application only supports `unary RPCs` and I am not sure if this setting will apply to that.

I am just looking to enforce/set a max number of active concurrent requests the server can handle. Would setting `maxConcurrentStreams` work or should I look at doing it in my code itself (I have done some rudimentary implementation for it but I would rather use something provided by grpc-go)?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `MaxConcurrentStreams` before, because for highload services you usually want to make the most from your hardware, and this limitation doesn't seem to make sense. Perhaps it's possible to achieve your goal with this setting, but you need to investigate, which kind of error is returned when `MaxConcurrentStreams` is achieved. I think that should be `GRPC`'s transport error, not your own, so you'll not be able to control error message and code.